# PRODUCTION環境で jQuery が動きません

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
#$ ->
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()

#$ ->
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $(".searchable").select2({
      width:      180,  # 横幅
      allowClear: true  # x で選択したものを削除できる
      # 詳細は http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation
    })
```

というjQueryを書いていますが、DEVELOPMENT環境では動きますが
PRODUCTION環境で動きません
PRECOMPILE済で
APPLICATION.JSをPUBLIC環境へおいたりもしましたが
全く動作してくれません。　現在DEVELOPMENT環境で動かしていますが
スピードが遅いので、なんとかPRODUCTION環境で動作するようにしたいので
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 複数の環境があるようですが(本番、開発etc)それらの違いは何でしょうか。

Comment: 「動きません」の詳細な説明が必要です。何がどう動かないのでしょうか？

Comment: config\environmentsの下のdevelopment.rbを適用した場合
production.rbを適用した場合のＲＡＩＬＳの動作が異なるという意味です
コマンドプロンプトでrails s で起動した場合はJQUERYが動くのですが
rails s -e production で起動させるとＪＱＵＥＲＹが動かないのです

Comment: ＪＱＵＥＲＹが動かないとは、追加ボタンをクリックしたとき、1対多の形でフォームをつくっており、明細行がクリック時に追加されるというＪＱＵＥＲＹなのですが、開発環境では追加ボタンをクリックすると明細行が追加されますが、PRODUCTION環境では追加ボタンをおしても反応が何もなく、明細行が追加できないのです。よろしくお願いします

Comment: 上記のJQUERYは
http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20141208/1418018874
を参考にしてつくりました。作ったPGはこれと同じような動きです

Comment: 自己解決できました
gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'をいれることで動くようになりました環境編集としてRAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILESに1が設定できずにいたせいだと思われます

Answer (score 0):

自己解決できました gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'をいれることで動くようになりました環境編集としてRAILS_SER‌​VE_STATIC_FILESに1が設定‌​できずにいたせいだと思われます – Yuko Tobaru